# How can I write a delete postgresql query in Python flask

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I was trying to delete from a database table using flask and postgresql, but I keep having error in mysql syntax.Please how can I implement it. The two ways below did not work. Nb: The id is to be retrieved from a variable. I'm actually new to python from php.

```
my_id = 3
del = engine.execute("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = '{my_id}'")
del = engine.execute("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id=:id", {"id":my_id})
```

Answer (score 1):

**SQLAlchemy 1.x**

You could just do this:

```
my_id = 3
result = engine.execute("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = %s", my_id)
```

or

```
result = engine.execute("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = %(id)s", {'id': my_id})
```

In both of these statements you are assuming that the underlying database connection library (for example psycopg2 or pg8000) are using %-formatting to bind query parameters.  To avoid this dependency you can use [sqlalchemy.text](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) to build the query string:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
result = engine.execute(sa.text("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = :id"), id=my_id)
```

letting sqlalchemy build the query and handle parameter binding and quoting.

You should **NOT** use ordinary python string formatting functions to bind query parameters:

```
engine.execute("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = %s" % my_id)
engine.execute("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = {}".format(my_id))
engine.execute(f"DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = {my_id}")
```

Using these methods may expose your application to SQL injection attacks, because the  query parameters may not be quoted correctly.
A point of style: you can't use `del` as a variable name.  Python already has the [del statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement), and attempting to reassign the name `del` results in a `SyntaxError`.  Also, the `ResultProxy` object returned by a DELETE statement doesn't contain any rows, so there is little point assigning the result to a variable.

**SQLAlchemy 2.0**

In SQLAlchemy 2.0 (still in development), or in SQLAlchemy 1.4 with the engine's `future` flag set to `True`, raw SQL strings can no longer be executed directly*, and neither is it possible to use an implicit connection as in `engine.execute`.

Raw SQL statements must be wrapped by `sqlalchemy.text`, with parameters passed as dictionaries, so the code would look like this:

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sa.text('DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = :id'), {'id': my_id})
```

**Object-oriented Style**

Regardless of the version you are using, you can operate on a [Table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) object to delete rows

```py
# Reflect an existing table from the database.
tbl = sa.Table('my_table', sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(tbl.delete().where(tbl.c.id == my_id))
    conn.execute(sa.delete(tbl).where(tbl.c.id == my_other_id))
```

---

* You can still execute raw SQL using [Connection.exec_driver_sql](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.exec_driver_sql), if you really must.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQLAlchemy.ORM

```
my_id = XXX
db.session.query.filter(Table.id == my_id).delete()
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score -2):

There are several ways to build up strings in python, if you're using python3 then I would use f-strings, which your second line of code is almost using.  You just need to add an "f" before your quotes, so your code becomes:

```
del = engine.execute(f"DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = '{my_id}'")
```

Here is some info on formatting strings in python and using f-strings https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/